# Error: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a function that is supposed to take an array and sort it from the smallest string size to the largest and then print it by using injection sort.

On the line: `while (j >=0) and (len(b[j]) > key):`

I get this error:

> object of type 'int' has no len()

Code:

```
def list_sort(b):
    for i in range(1, len(b)):
        key = len(b[i])
        j = i - 1 
        while (j >=0) and (len(b[j]) > key):
            b[j+1] = b[j]
            j = j - 1
        b[j+1] = key
    for i in range( len(b) ):
        print (b[i])

list_sort(name)
```

Comment: What were you expecting `len(b_list[j])` to be?

Comment: If you get the error where you say you do, then you should also get it at `keyValue = len(b_list[i])`

Comment: `b_list[j+1] = keyValue` - are you sure you're assigning the right value there?

Comment: You say you're sorting an array of strings, but it sounds like it's an array of numbers.

Comment: Except where used inside of `range()`, are you sure you mean to use `len()`? It looks like maybe you want just `b_list[j]` or `j` or something.

Comment: @EL_DON He says he wants to sort by string size.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the array is a mix of strings and numbers, since you don't get an error on `keyValue = len(b_list[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you generated the error to begin with, since the input of `["alice", "bob", "sally"]` didn't crash, but it does generate numbers.

That's probably because you assign `b_list[j+1] = keyValue`, where `keyValue = len(b_list[i])`, which will be an int, and so, if you ever hit that element again, and try to `len()` on it, that's the error you are seeing.

Now, re-implementing this from the [Wikipedia pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort)

```
def insertion_sort(A):
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        j = i
        s1 = A[j-1]
        s2 = A[j]
        while j > 0 and len(s1) > len(s2):
            # swap A[j] and A[j-1]
            tmp = A[j-1]
            A[j-1] = A[j]
            A[j] = tmp

            j = j - 1

name_list = ["alice", "bob", "sally"]
insertion_sort(name_list)

for name in name_list:
    print name
```

Prints out

```
bob
alice
sally
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `atleast_1d()` or `tolist()` to make sure that objects will have `len()` when dealing with a potential mixture of scalars and arrays/lists.

Comment: He wants the length of a string, not a list.

Comment: @Barmar apparently his list of strings contains objects that do not have `len()`. This will let his script run and do the sorting. He can then find the lengthless objects at one end of the result, which may help with debugging.

Comment: But `tolist()` will turn all the strings into a list of one string, so everything will have len = 1.

Comment: The problem, as others noted, is that he has a bug in the loop that replaces strings with numbers. `b_list[j+1] = keyValue`.

Comment: @Barmar I see that you are right. This answer does not solve the problem at all. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a mixed list of integers and strings and want to sort by length of the strings. If that is the case, convert the entire list to like types -- strings -- before sorting.

Given:

```
>>> li=[1,999,'a','bbbb',0,-3]
```

You can do:

```
>>> sorted(map(str, li), key=len)   
['1', 'a', '0', '-3', '999', 'bbbb']
```

If you want a two key sort by length then ascibetible, you can do:

```
>>> sorted(map(str, li), key=lambda e: (len(e), e))
['0', '1', 'a', '-3', '999', 'bbbb']
```

You can sort without changing the object type by adding `str` to the key function:

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda e: (len(str(e)), str(e)))
[0, 1, 'a', -3, 999, 'bbbb']
```